# POST request application-x-www-form-urlencoded with AFNetworking2.0 failure error response code =-1011

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to make a POST request with content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' using AFNetworking's [POST:parameters:success:failure] method.

The post-request works perfectly on POSTMAN.

Since i'm sending x-www-form-urlencoded data I am using a AFHTTPRequestSerializer as the requestSerializer of my AFHTTPRequestOperationManager (the responseSerializer is a AFJSONResponseSerializer).

I pass the parameters of my POST request body as a NSDictionary to the 'parameters' argument.

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
failure: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x1700f2d00 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x174231ae0> { URL: https://xx.x.x.xxx/oauth/token } { status code: 404, headers {
Allow = POST;
"Cache-Control" = private;
Connection = close;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Wed, 15 Jul 2015 08:11:01 GMT";
Server = Apache;
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=15768000";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://10.9.3.202/oauth/token, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b22636f 6465223a 3430342c 226d6573 73616765 223a224e 6f742046 6f756e64 227d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)}
```

Please help !
Thanks

Comment: "Request failed: not found (404)" return this error means your requested page not found (this page not in server).

Comment: thanks for the explanation but that's not possible.. I can access it with postman.

Comment: please add your code.@joeri Bultheel

Comment: I was sending the wrong parameters to the server. problem solved.

Comment: ok bro.... @Joeri Bhltheel